# Contrast stretching an image by openCV

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to stretch the contrast of an image to the range of 0-255 using cvNormalize. But when I print out the output pixel values, Some negative numbers appear as the pixel value. I appreciate if you help me find out where the origin of the problem is. This is the code:

```
cvNormalize(srcImage, dstImage, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX );

for ( int pixel = 0; pixel < dstImage->height * dstImage->width; pixel++ ) {
    printf("%d\t",*(dstImage->imageData + pixel));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `imageData`'s type is `char*` and `char` can be nagative (range is [-128, 127]). Try casting to `unsigned char`.

See [docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#iplimage).

Comment: Same problem arises when I typecast it to unsigned char:                    printf("%d\t", (uchar*)*(dstImage->imageData + pixel))

Comment: what about `(uchar)*(dstImage->imageData + pixel))`?